# How to solve stargazer error asking for .stargazer.wrap function

Tags: r, stargazer

I keeep getting this error every time I try to run the stargazer function and I don't understand. I have uninstalled the package, installed it again, restarted R, uninstalled and installed R.

Error in .stargazer.wrap(..., type = type, title = title, style = style,  :
could not find function ".stargazer.wrap"

The strangest thing is that stargazer was initially working and then it suddenly started throwing this error, every time I run it, with any type of data. With or without data. An example of data that I have tried:

```
model <- lm(mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars)

stargazer(model)

Error in .stargazer.wrap(..., type = type, title = title, style = style,  : 
  could not find function ".stargazer.wrap"
```

I have just realised that when running it like this it does work!

```
stargazer::stargazer(model, type='text')
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including data and your code which can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Have a look at [ask] and [mre]

Comment: I have now! Is it more understandable?

Comment: Have you resolved your own question now? Did you load the package with `library(stargazer)`?

Comment: Not really. I don't understand why I need the double semicolon to use the stargazer function when I didn't before... And yes, I loaded the package with library(stargazer).

Comment: Usually you load a package using `library("package name")` at the start of your script. This gives you access to all the functions of that package, in your case the function `stargazer()`. An alternative approach to accessing functions from packages which are installed on your computer but not loaded into the script is to use the double colon notation "package name"::"function name"; in your case:  `stargazer::stargazer()`